# Live streamign using Kaltura and Wowza + FMLE

Tags: live-streaming, wowza, kaltura

I am trying to create live streaming using Kaltura + Wowza + FMLE.

I have Wowza and Kaltura setup on a single server.
I stream camera feed from FMLE to wowza, which is working ok.
I am able to see feed from camera when I open live stream under kLive application from Wowza.

Problem is, When I open live stream from KMC then i am not able to see the stream and I get following errors in the log file.

```
[0.000233] [xx.xx.xx.xx] [911412886] [API] [KalturaBaseService->isPermitted] ERR: exception 'Exception' with message 'Kaltura network is not allowed' in /opt/kaltura/app/infra/log/KalturaLog.php:82
#0 /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3/lib/KalturaBaseService.php(181): KalturaLog::err('Kaltura network...')
#7 {main}
[0.000699] [xx.xx.xx.xx] [911412886] [API] [KalturaFrontController->getExceptionObject] ERR: exception 'KalturaAPIException' with message 'The access to service [wowza_liveconversionprofile->serve] is forbidden' in /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3/lib/KalturaBaseService.php:117
#0 /opt/kaltura/app/plugins/media/wowza/services/LiveConversionProfileService.php(16): KalturaBaseService->initService('wowza_liveconve...', 'liveConversionP...', 'serve')
```

I have followed steps as mentioned in below link for Wowza + kaltura integration:

> https://github.com/kaltura/media-server/blob/3.0.8/Installation.md

What may be the cause of these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those kind of errors are usually related to session permissions.

In case of `wowza_liveconversionprofile.serve` it requires `ALWAYS_ALLOWED_FROM_INTERNAL_IP_ACTIONS` or `ALWAYS_ALLOWED_PERMISSION_HYBRID_ECDN` permission.

`ALWAYS_ALLOWED_FROM_INTERNAL_IP_ACTIONS` will be added automatically if the request is coming from an internal IP. You can configure internal IPs using the configuration option `internal_ip_range`.

`ALWAYS_ALLOWED_PERMISSION_HYBRID_ECDN` can probably be added to partner's session automatically by enabling 'Hybrid eCDN Architecture` under admin console's partner configuration screen.

Let me know if that solution worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where can I find the configuration/permission parameter `ALWAYS_ALLOWED_FROM_INTERNAL_IP_ACTIONS` or `ALWAYS_ALLOWED_PERMISSION_HYBRID_ECDN`, also I have my Wowza and Kaltura running on same server so I have kept `internal_ip_range` in `/opt/kaltura/app/configurations/local.ini` as `127.0.0.1`. Also `Hybrid eCDN Architecture` is also enabled in admin console for that particular partner.

Comment: Those permissions are added to the KS depending on the role, partner id and different conditions (like the internal IP one). The permissions are saved in `permission` table and linked to services (`permission_item` table) using `permission_to_permission_item` table.